# App not going to next view in iPad Simulator on iOS 6

Tags: ios, object

I have an older iOS app that has 2 views, a MainViewController and a FlipsideViewController. For some reason, when I press a button that switches from the MainViewController to the FlipsideViewController, the app just freezes, and the log shows no crash. This only happens on the iPad simulator with iOS 6. The app works fine on the iPhone simulator with iOS 6.

Here's the code I'm using in my MainViewController to switch to the other:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView-iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
}
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```

If I put an NSLog() statement in the top of the viewDidLoad of FlipsideViewController, it does output to the debug log. But the view is never shown.

It should also be noted that the FlipsideViewController does contain MPMusicPlayerController code, but this line has been commented out since it usually causes issues on the simulator:

```
self.musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention that it works fine on the iPad simulator in iOS 5.

Comment: I determined what's causing the issue, but I can't figure out how to fix. It's due to having multiple UITableViews on the FlipsideViewController. If I delete them and only leave one, it works. But if there's more than one, then it never goes to the Flipside view. Any idea how to fix?